# Using ngFor in Array

Tags: angular

I have data showing up in my console as this. I want to show them in a dropdown.

```
["Hello", "Hello"]
0:"Hello"
1:"Hello"
length:2
__proto__:Array(0)
```

This is what I tried:

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let x of greeting" [value]="x">{{x}}<option>
</select>
```

But nothing is showing up.

And when I use it this way:

```
<select>
  <option>{{greeting}}<option>
</select>
```

It shows up as one single item in the dropdown as Hello,Hello

UPDATE: Actual Response

```
{
status: 200,
message: "Rooms are available",
available: "yes",
remaining_room: 10,
price: "[1800,1200]",
extra_person_price: "["500","200"]",
extra_child_price: "["500","100"]",
plan_type: "["EP","PT"]",
plan_name: "["Summer Plan","Winter Plan"]",
}
```

Response from Network Tab

```
{status: 200, message: "Rooms are available", available: "yes", remaining_room: 10,…}
available
:
"yes"
extra_child_price
:
"["500","100"]"
extra_person_price
:
"["500","200"]"
message
:
"Rooms are available"
plan_name
:
"["Summer Plan","Costume Plan"]"
plan_type
:
"["CP","others"]"
price
:
"[1800,1200]"
remaining_room
:
10
status
:
200
```

Comment: It seems to be working for me, check [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/M1teJQOeWJMPIA7VUegC?p=preview)

Comment: @PankajParkar Maybe because I am using `JSON.parse` on that data since it comes as a string from an API. It worked when I used `[value]="greeting[x]`. But I am also getting an extra empty item in the dropdown at the end. Like a third item.

Comment: @SLASH `greeting[x]` is not correct answer.

Comment: @SLASH could you reproduce bug in the plunker..???

Comment: I could not reproduce the bug, but I am doing something like this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8Tzk32OeuJvgEaXWFABE?p=preview)

Comment: @SLASH You cannot even parse `"['Hello', 'Hello']"`, it's not valid. Could you add to your question how your json response looks like? :)

Comment: @AJT_82 you're absolutely correct, it should be `"[\"Hello\", \"Hello\"]"`

Comment: @PankajParkar Sure :) But I'm still wondering how the response actually looks like. I'm of suspicious nature :P

Comment: @AJT_82 The actual response is of string types. I have added them in the question.

Comment: @SLASH So, this is how the response looks like in the network tab? How do you assign this value, since it's not JSON? Could you show the http-request? And still making sure that this is the actual response you can see in the network tab, yes?

Comment: @AJT_82 using `JSON.parse()` method

Comment: Well JSON parse would throw an error, since this is not parsable.

Comment: @SLASH That's why I asked how the response looks like when it comes. Can you post exactly how the response looks like int the network tab, since as said, trying to parse that would not even remotely work :) You actual response should look something like this: `"[\"Hello\", \"Hello\"]"` to be able to parse it.

Comment: @AJT_82 Currently I am able to use `JSON.parse` on the data and then use `*ngFor` to display them. It is being displayed but also I am getting an extra empty option in the dropdown

Comment: @SLASH could you just post how the response looks like in the network tab please, so that I could perhaps help you.

Comment: @AJT_82 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141344/discussion-between-slash-and-ajt-82).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our discussion you tried to iterate the wrong variable (which was still a string), so:

This works: Since you have mixed data in your response, from which you need to parse some of, so in your subscribe you could create an object, where you then parse the parts you need, here's just the partial data:

```ts
getData() {
  this.service.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      // assign values to obj, and parse the ones you need to parse:
      this.obj = {"remaining_room":data.remaining_room, "price":JSON.parse(data.price)}
    })
}
```

Then you can refer to the object in your select:

```html
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let price of obj?.price">{{price}}</option>
</select>
```

Here's a **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VUHw1EkTfyRi1ISUv0FS?p=preview)** with the above code.